# impossible to delete a cookie with axios next js and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, next.js

i try to delete two cookies (token and refresh in httpOnly) but impossible.

I tried with `res.clearCookie("cookieName")`
and with `res.setHeader`

it tells me that the cookie has been deleted, no error but when I look (regardless of the browser) the cookies are still present

I put CORS, withCredential on the side of axios but nothing to do I do not see my error

**gateway.js** :

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const csurf = require("csurf")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const helmet = require("helmet");
// var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
const corsConfig = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
};

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }))
app.set('trust proxy', true);



app.use(helmet()); // middleware for secure app
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded, basically can only parse incoming Request Object if strings or arrays
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// combines the 2 above, then you can parse incoming Request Object if object, with nested objects, or generally any type.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

in gateway js i set the cors and other things

**routerFileForAuth.js**
this file sends a message to a queue to disconnect it does some action (no importance here) once finished I have to delete the cookie

```
router.get('/logout', cookieJwtAuth, (req, res) => {
    try {
       
        const eventName = uuidv4();
        const msg = {label: "authenticationCibestService", type: "cibestLogout", verb: "GET", eventName: eventName, body: req.cookies.refresh};
        sender.emitMsgToSend.emit('send', 'authenticationCibestServiceQueue', JSON.stringify(msg));
        receiver.emitMsgReceived.once(eventName.toString(), (data, status) => {
        console.log("arrivé dans le emiit message de logout",req.cookies.token)
           res.clearCookie('token')
           res.clearCookie('refresh')
           res.sendStatus(status)
    
    });
    } catch (error) {
        res(400).json(error.toString());
    }
});
```

**dashboard.js**

```
const dashboard = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>map</p>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};
export default dashboard;
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const headers = ctx.req.headers;
  const res = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url:"http://localhost:3001/cibest-admin/logout",
    headers: ctx?.req?.headers?.cookie ? {cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie} : undefined,
    withCredentials:true,
  })
  return { props: { data: res.data } };
};
```

this file it's just for testing a logout when i load a page

this is the screen of cookie in chrome :
https://ibb.co/Qr36jNH

tech list:

- NextJs
- Axios
- Express/node
- Rabbitmq
- Microservices
- APIgateway

Edit :
The delete cookie work with postman, and can work with next js only like this :

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const logout = async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const res = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url:"http://localhost:3001/cibest-admin/logout",
      //headers: req?.headers?.cookie ? {cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie} : undefined,
      withCredentials:true,
    })
  }
  return (
    <nav>
      <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

but still not work with getServiSideProps or static or initialProps

Comment: "it tells me that the cookie has been deleted, no error but when I look (regardless of the browser) the cookies are still present" — How are you looking?

Comment: it's httpOnly cookie so i use DevTools i go in application and check in Cookies if they are here

Comment: It's a small mistake sometimes, but have you refreshed your browser's inspect window before looking?

Comment: Yes i refresh after go in the page (web browser or the Arrow in console )

Comment: Good to know : if do this
 ```   res.setHeader(
            "Set-Cookie", [
            `token=deleted; Max-Age=0`,
            `refresh=deleted; Max-Age=0`]
          );
```
in the dashboard js file in Axios the cookie are deleted (but i want to do this from my gateway not next js)